# Cache read controller

Tags: cpu-cache

Does the cpu interface with a memory controller to read the cache? What happens when data is not in the cache, a cache miss, does it automatically fetch the data?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Address_translation

Comment: Does the cpu interface with a controller before accessing the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about on die structures are scarce for the intel CPUs. You can look at https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen#Memory_Controller for information on AMD CPUs. Especially the following images:

[image: AMD CPU die]

[image: AMD CPU description]

You have the actual die seen under a microscope for the Zen microarchitecture. You clearly see the L3 and L2 controllers. There is one L2 cache per core while there is a shared big L3 cache in the middle.